# Prevent gestures in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, gesture

Is it possible to prevent some gestures being recognized in a `UIWebView`?

I have a `UIWebView` which loads HTML / JS and the JS responds to a gesture where the user pulls down the view with two fingers.

As I hooked up another action within the view to this gesture I don't want the `UIWebView` to respond to this gesture.

Is this possible?